# Euler equations and pressure

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, mathematical-modeling

Let $\Omega$ be a region between two concentric cylinders with radius $R_1$ and $R_2$, where $R_1 < R_2$. A velocity field is given by (in cylindric coorinates $r, \psi, z$):
$$v = (- ( A/r + Br) \sin(\psi), (A/r + Br) \cos(\psi), 0)$$

where $ A= \dfrac{R_1^2 R_2^2 (\omega_2 - \omega_1)}{R_2^2 - R_2^2}$, $B= - \dfrac{R_1^2 \omega_1 - R_2^2 \omega_2}{R_2^2 - R_1^2}$.

Why is $v$ a stationary solution of the Euler equations with $\rho = 1$ ?

Edit: And how does the pressure look like ?

Comment: Is that $\sinh(\psi)$ or $\sin(d\psi)$ or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's a normal sin --> typo :/